# Redux - concat not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, redux

I have models`Language`,`Entities`,`EntitiesInfo`

```
export interface Language
{
 name:string;
 status:string;
 id:number;
}

export interface Entities {
  languages?:Language[];
}

export interface EntitiesInfo {
  language?:Language;
}
```

And below is my `addEntityAction`

```
export const ADD_ENTITY = 'Add Entity';

export interface AddEntityAction extends Action {
  entity:string;
  data:EntitiesInfo;
}
export const addEntity:ActionCreator<AddEntityAction> = (entity:string,data:EntitiesInfo):AddEntityAction => {
  return {
    type:ADD_ENTITY,
    entity:entity,
    data:data
  }
}
```

this is my state and reducer:

```
export interface EntityState {
  entitiesList:Entities;
  entitiesInfo?:EntitiesInfo;
}

const initialState:EntityState = {
  entitiesList:null,
  entitiesInfo:null
}

export const EntityReducer = function (state:EntityState = initialState,action:Action):EntityState{
  switch(action.type)
  {

    case EntityActions.ADD_ENTITY:
      const infoAdd = (<EntityActions.AddEntityAction>action);
      switch(infoAdd.entity)
      {
        case "language":
          state.entitiesList.languages = state.entitiesList.languages.concat(infoAdd.data.language);//this not working

          return {entitiesList:state.entitiesList};
      }


    default:
      return state;
  }


}
```

my example dispatch:

```
this.entity = ["language":{"id":100,"name":"English","status":"Active"}]
this.store.dispatch(EntityActions.addEntity("language",this.entity))
```

my `getState()`

[image]

The language English does not merge in `state.entitiesList.languages` array.

Comment: Why you modify previous state? It's the violations of the immutability principle.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that you should use [pure functions](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions). In your case you are mutating previous state what is highly not recommended.

Comment: I see. Can you please post an answer for my reducer. Thanks

Comment: As for me code should returns new state. Try to debug with [Redux DevTool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) to see what happened to store and how it's dispatched.